Best practise to ignore null values from model
Lets assume we got the following model:
export interface UserModel {
   usename: string;
   password: string;
   email: string;
   address: string;
   phoneNumber: string
}

The address is optional and the user doesn't add any so the value of it is null or empty string.
In cases where the value is null, empty string or even undefined for any possible reason I would like to ignore
address property from the object.
What is the best way to ignore any properties with unwanted values keeping my code strongly typed ?
PS:

Adding an external library to clean the unwanted values is not my goal.

Correlated service is a POST method and expecting a UserModel type.


The following is what I tried:
function cleanUserModel(user: UserModel): UserModel {
    const cleanedUser: Partial<UserModel> = { ...user };
    
    Object.keys(cleanedUser).forEach(key => {
        const value = cleanedUser[key as keyof UserModel];
        if (value === null || value === '' || value === undefined) {
            delete cleanedUser[key as keyof UserModel];
        }
    });
    
    return cleanedUser as UserModel;
}

Works fine. But wondering if there is a cleaner way, with the same result!

"What is the best way to ignore any properties with unwanted values keeping my code strongly typed ?" for a start, if these properties can be null or undefined you haven't typed them as such. Which most likely means that you don't have strictNullChecks enabled. If not, it's also likely that you don't have strict enabled, either. These should be the first steps to having strongly typed code - when the type correspond to the real values you can get and don't hide nullish possibilities.

Also, seems that even then you're still trying to hide nullish values - your cleanUserModel claims it returns UserModel but it doesn't. It's returning Partial<UserModel> but hides that information from consumers, therefore weakening the typing in your application, since you can now never be sure whether a non-optional property actually exists on the model or not. cleanUserModel could return a value like { username: "Fred" } but if you tried to do data.email TS would not stop you. Because you've yourself told TS that the property must be there. It's what the type says.

@VLAZ strict is disabled. The project is old enough, so many engineers add their pieces to that. There are cases in which null values are needed for business purposes.
I understand how the Partial works and this is why this post was created, to get a different approach. Could you provide some?

This question is similar to: Remove blank attributes from an Object in Javascript. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't know if you will find this cleaner but I have a similar function:
  static purgeEmptyValues(obj: object) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj).filter(
        ([_, v]) => v !== undefined && v !== null && v !== ''
      )
    );
  }

EDIT (with generic type):
  static purgeEmptyValues<T extends {[key:string]:any}>(obj: T) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj).filter(
        ([_, v]) => v !== undefined && v !== null && v !== ''
      )
    ) as T;
  }


This is even less type-safe than OP's one, since it loses all type information.

@VLAZ I edited the post and added the type information as a generic type but I guess your other comments bellow the original post apply to this solution as well.
